# How to align guides relative to an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I have four objects and I need to align guides to the middle of each. Is there a way to align the guides relative to those objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw paths.

Align the paths to the objects....

Then select the paths and make them guides (View > Guides > Make Guides)

Comment: It's not what i wanted but you are best introducing me to this technique!  I will use it as best i can in the future so i will mark the answer as solved! Thanks a lot Metis:)!